# Get posted filename in PHP

Tags: php

I am getting the values of posted data with php.

I am using:

```
if (isset($_POST['fieldname'])) {
$field1 = $_POST['fieldname'];
}
```

This works correctly and I can return the value using:

```
echo $field1;
```

My problem is that there is a field called ul_image which contains the name of an image and it's for upload.

I've tried:

```
if (isset($_POST['ul_image'])) {
$field2 = $_POST['ul_image'];
}

echo $field2;
```

but this returns nothing.

I'm out of ideas so does anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: Read http://www.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.post-method.php

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The file data is contained in `$_FILES['ul_image']`. It contains an array with the following keys: `name` (original filename), `type` (MIME type), `size` (file size in bytes), `tmp_name` (temporary path on your server), `error` (any errors).

Then to store the file permanently use `move_uploaded_file($_FILES['ul_image']['tmp_name'], $destination)`. The reason is added security; this function makes sure a hacker has not manipulated your script to move arbitrary files on your server.

Answer (score 2):

If the input type is 'file', it ends up in the $_FILES array, not in the $_POST array. You will then have to find a way to actually get the image to your server - or wherever.

Start reading here: https://www.php.net/move_uploaded_file

Comment: More info here: http://nl3.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.post-method.php