# How to move file to another folder?

Tags: php, html, forms, file, input

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Main Page</title>
</head>
<body>
<h2>Main Page</h2>
<form  method="post" action="index.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input type="file" name="filename">
<input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="102400"/>
<input type="submit"  value="Upload file">
<br>
<?php
echo $_FILES['filename']['name'];
$uploads_dir = '/uploads';
$tmp_name = $_FILES['filename']['tmp_name'][$key];
$name = $_FILES['filename']['name'][$key];
move_uploaded_file($tmp_name, "$uploads_dir/$name");
?>
</body>
</html>
```

How can i move this file to folder?
I try to use move_uploaded_file
but it downst moving...(

Comment: Shouldn't `echo $filename;` be `echo $_POST["filename"];` ?

Comment: Have you looked at the manual yet? http://www.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.post-method.php

Comment: possible duplicate of [Get posted filename in PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10940620/get-posted-filename-in-php)

Answer (score 2):

Use this

```
echo $_FILES['filename']['name'];
```

As **BrianDriscoll** pointed out, the declaration of `MAX_FILE_SIZE` must precede the file input field.

```
<form action = "index.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="102400" />
    <input type="file" name="filename" />
    <input type="submit"  value="Upload file" />
</form>
```

**$_FILES['filename']['name']** - `name` contains the original path of the user uploaded 
file.

**$_FILES['filename']['tmp_name']** - `tmp_name` contains the path to the temporary file that resides on the server. The file should exist on the server in a temporary directory with a temporary name.

See this [tutorial on Tizag](http://www.tizag.com/phpT/fileupload.php/).

Comment: yes,my page is index.php and it's still doesnt working(

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [`$_FILES`](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.files.php) array to get information about the uploaded file.

Do `var_dump($_FILES)` to see what it contains.

`$_FILES['filename']` will contain the information of the file.

- `$_FILES['filename']['name']` as the original file name
- `$_FILES['filename']['tmp_name']` as the path to the temp file that is on the server. This will get deleted unless you move it! Move it using [`move_uploaded_file()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.move-uploaded-file.php)

I recommend reading [this tutorial](http://www.tizag.com/phpT/fileupload.php)

Comment: okay, i move in that way and  cant move

Comment: Move the max size field to be above the input.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to what others have said, you're **also** missing the declaration of MAX_FILE_SIZE, from the PHP manual:

> The MAX_FILE_SIZE hidden field (measured in bytes) must precede the
>   file input field, and its value is the maximum filesize accepted by
>   PHP. This form element should always be used as it saves users the
>   trouble of waiting for a big file being transferred only to find that
>   it was too large and the transfer failed. Keep in mind: fooling this
>   setting on the browser side is quite easy, so never rely on files with
>   a greater size being blocked by this feature. It is merely a
>   convenience feature for users on the client side of the application.
>   The PHP settings (on the server side) for maximum-size, however,
>   cannot be fooled.

`<input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="102400"/>`

Answer (score -1):

You need to define the action-attribute of the form.

```
<form  method="post" action="" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

**edit**: and what abhshkdz wrote.

Comment: A blank action attribute will simply post to the same page, which based on OP's code looks to be the desired behavior.